# How to use AWS EC2 Scheduler?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to start/stop my EC2 instance at 8:30 PM - 8:35 PM daily to run 
cron jobs.

I have an EC2 instance set up tagged with `0430;0435;utc;all` to account for this.

Now my confusion is that my Rule needs a Scheduler expression. I get that I need to kick off the lambda function to start/stop the ec2 instance, but I thought that's what the tag was for.

I'm currently using the cron expression `30 4 * * ? *` for the rule schedule and it does not work. What am I supposed to put for this rule schedule expression to do what I want?

Anyone unfamiliar with what I'm referring to: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/ec2-scheduler/overview.html

Comment: You want to stop and start your EC2 instances at regular intervals using AWS Lambda. Please go through the below links https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html#CronExpressions

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question correctly below might help.

The purpose of Scheduler Expression is to trigger the cloud-watch event to kick of the lambda function. Basically it is how often you want the function to scan your EC2 instances to action on.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/ec2-scheduler/deployment.html

[image]

Below link might help you to figure out the cron expression formatting that will best fit.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm

Comment: Ah, this makes much more sense. The tag is used to help the lambda function determine if the instance needs to be started or stopped. Essentially, I need to set it up so that the rule scans every 6 minutes so that as soon as the crons are done, the function checks the instance/tag and shuts it down

Comment: Another way to achieve auto start/stop without polling, that I can think of - 

Assuming you know the cron start time, you can fire the lambda from the cloudwatch scheduler to bring up the instance a few mins earlier.

In the cron script you can put in a last step as writing a file to s3. A putObject trigger can then trigger the lambda to shutdown this instance. 

Within the lambda you can write logic to do basic validations - tag etc, and also read the json from the event (which can have something like "instance: start") or the s3 notification.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use service like [CloudTiming](https://cloudtiming.com) they have user friendly interface, there is no any cron records. One negative point here it's not free.